# Mapbox iOS - vector tiles projection

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

mapbox ios sdk version 6.2.1

Hi, I am trying to display fires vector tiles layer on mapbox but I can't make it show on correct position.

I add fire layer like this:

```
let source = MGLVectorTileSource(identifier: "VIIRS_NOAA20_Thermal_Anomalies_375m_All", tileURLTemplates: ["https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/VIIRS_NOAA20_Thermal_Anomalies_375m_All/default/2021-03-02/500m/{z}/{y}/{x}.mvt"], options: nil)
style.addSource(source)

let layer = MGLCircleStyleLayer(identifier: "VIIRS_NOAA20_Thermal_Anomalies_375m_All_v2_NRT", source: source)
layer.sourceLayerIdentifier = "VIIRS_NOAA20_Thermal_Anomalies_375m_All_v2_NRT"
layer.circleRadius = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 2)
layer.circleColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.red)
style.addLayer(layer)
```

It's displayed but on wrong position. Shifted to the right and top.
[image]

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks

**Edit**: It seems that issue is that Mapbox uses EPSG:3857 projection but Vector tiles from server use EPSG:4326 projection. Is there any way how to transform that on client?